# How to store Dstream data(json) into cassandra?

Tags: json, cassandra, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, spark-cassandra-connector

```
       val topics= "test"
       val zkQuorum="localhost:2181"
       val group="test-consumer-group"    
       val sparkConf = new org.apache.spark.SparkConf()
          .setAppName("XXXXX")
          .setMaster("local[*]")
          .set("cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
          .set("cassandra.connection.port", "9042")

        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
        ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")
        val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap

        val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)
```

I am getting DStream (json) like this

```
[{"id":100,"firstName":"Beulah","lastName":"Fleming","gender":"female","ethnicity":"SpEd","height":167,"address":27,"createdDate":1494489672243,"lastUpdatedDate":1494489672244,"isDeleted":0},{"id":101,"firstName":"Traci","lastName":"Summers","gender":"female","ethnicity":"Frp","height":181,"address":544,"createdDate":1494510639611,"lastUpdatedDate":1494510639611,"isDeleted":0}]
```

By this above program i am getting json data in DStream.
How i will process this Dstream data and store into Cassandra or elastic search? Then how i will retrieve data from DStream(in json format) and store in Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `com.datastax.spark.connector._`, convert to elements of the stream to appropriate case classes

```
case class Record(id: String, firstName: String, ...)
val colums = SomeColums("id", "first_name", ...)
val mapped = lines.map(whateverDataYouHave => fuctionThatReutrnsARecordObject)
```

and save it using implicit function saveToCassandra

```
mapped.saveToCassandra(KEYSPACE_NAME, TABLE_NAME, columns)
```

For more information check documentation https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md